# How can I create a .zip file for each folder within another folder?

Tags: zip

Under the folder `images\`, I have the following folders:

- `Usa\`
- `Italy\`
- `Japan\`

etc..

I want a script that creates a `.zip` for each of these folders, so I have `usa.zip` , `italy.zip`, `japan.zip`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 12):

I assume this is Windows, as you are using backslashes.

Get [7za.exe](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sevenzip/7za920.zip) (the command-line version of [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)) and put it in your `%PATH%`.

Then run this within your `Images\` directory:

```
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %G in (`dir /b /a:d "%cd%"`) do 7za a -r -tzip "%~G.zip" "%~G"
```

Or in a batch script:

```
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%G in (`dir /b /a:d "%cd%"`) do 7za a -r -tzip "%%~G.zip" "%%~G"
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the folders have spaces in their name.

Comment: @jiggunjer Yes, you're right. I have fixed it to work with spaces in folder names.

Comment: This works even with normal 7zip executable.
I updated 7za to "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" and it worked without issue.

Comment: I can confirm that the above works with 7zip "out of the box" without any other download. I update my path to include 7z.exe and ran for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %G in (`dir /b /a:d "%cd%"`) do 7z a -r -tzip "%~G.zip" "%~G" without issues. Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 12):

You can use [Winrar](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm) for this.

Select all your folders, right click and select `Add to archive`. Now select the option `Put each file to separate archive` under the tab `Files`:

[image]

Click OK and you're done. If you want .zip files instead of .rar, just select `ZIP` in the `General` tab under `Archive format`.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you are on Linux you could use a Bash script like this:

```
  #!/bin/bash

  IFS=$'\n'

  for f in $(find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d ); do
    zip -r "$f" "$f"
  done
```

This script will take the first argument as folder, in this case images, and recurse exactly one level deep to get all your folders (Usa, Italy and Japan) and zip them in the same place.

It will not delete old zip files or the source folders. Zip is smart enough to detect existing zip files and update them when run again. However, if you delete a file in the source folders **it will not** be deleted in the zip files. You might circumvent this behaviour by deleting existing files beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68490/16704) by [MvG](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20807/mvg) worked for me on Ubuntu:

> You can use this loop in `bash`:
>
> ```
> for i in */; do zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i"; done
> ```
>
> `i` is the name of the loop variable. `*/` means every subdirectory of
>   the current directory, and will include a trailing slash in those
>   names. Make sure you `cd` to the right place before executing this.
>   `"$i"` simply names that directory, including trailing slash. The
>   quotation marks ensure that whitespace in the directory name won't
>   cause trouble. `${i%/}` is like `$i` but with the trailing slash
>   removed, so you can use that to construct the name of the zip file.
>
> If you want to see how this works, include an `echo` before the `zip`
>   and you will see the commands printed instead of executed.